# Inserting into MySQL tables through SparkSQL, by querying from the same table

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a MySQL table that was created in MySQL like that:

```
create table nnll (a integer, b integer)
```

I've initialized pyspark (2.1) and executed the code:

```
sql('create table nnll using org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc options (url "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306", dbtable "prod.nnll", user \'user\', password \'pass\')')
sql('insert into  nnll select 1,2')
sql('insert into  nnll select * from nnll')
```

From some reason, I get the exception:

```
AnalysisException: u'Cannot insert overwrite into table that is also being read from.;;\nInsertIntoTable Relation[a#2,b#3] JDBCRelation(prod.nnll) [numPartitions=1], OverwriteOptions(false,Map()), false\n+- Project [a#2, b#3]\n   +- SubqueryAlias nnll\n      +- Relation[a#2,b#3] JDBCRelation(prod.nnll) [numPartitions=1]\n'
```

It seems like my insert statement is translated into insert overwrite statement by spark, because I'm trying to insert to the same table that I'm querying (on the same partition, I have only one).
Is there any way to avoid this, and make spark translate this query to a regular query?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Spark does not allow us to insert into the same table from which we are reading the data. We have to insert data other than the one we are reading from.

Comment: Hi,
I got the point. Assuming that I know that the insert query will always insert different data from the same data I read, how can I do it?
My MySQL table has no partitions (and I can't change it now), but my queries work like it could have been, i.e I always inserting to a newer "partition". How can I do it?

Comment: Spark does not allow us to insert into the same table from which we are reading the data. We have to insert data other than the one we are reading from...  YOU CAN do the append / overwrite via DF.write.mode(“append”) at scale from a table you have read. No sweat, so a little surprised at this statement.